# How to log to a Mac with a user from a trusted domain?

Tags: mac-osx, domain, active-directory

I have a Mac (running OSX 10.9.2) that I have bound to an Active Directory domain I own (domain A).  This domain has a two way transative trust to a 2nd domain (domain B).  How do I specify the domain to authenticate against when signing in?

Currently I can sign in as a local user, or a user of domain A using no domain prefix (just *user*, using domainA\user or user@domainA, however those won't work for domain B.  I am not an administrator of domain B, so I have no way to bind the Mac to the 2nd domain.

Comment: have you tried domain\username? Or, try user@fqdn

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that.  both username, domainA\username and username@domainA all work.  None of those three work for domainB.